# I need help understanding what some instructions mean

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I am learning x86 assembly and have some problems with understanding some of the instructions.  What does `sub    $0x10,%rsp` mean, and why GCC copied this `mov    $0x0,%eax` line two times?

```
0x0000000000001135 <+0>:    push   %rbp   
0x0000000000001136 <+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000000000001139 <+4>:    sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x000000000000113d <+8>:    movl   $0xa,-0x4(%rbp)  
0x0000000000001144 <+15>:   mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000000000001147 <+18>:   mov    %eax,%esi
0x0000000000001149 <+20>:   lea    0xeb4(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2004
0x0000000000001150 <+27>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000001155 <+32>:   callq  0x1030 <printf@plt>
0x000000000000115a <+37>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
0x000000000000115f <+42>:   leaveq 
0x0000000000001160 <+43>:   retq
```

Comment: Have you looked up what those instructions mean in the reference manual? Also, why wouldn't the compiler happen to use `mov $0x0,%eax` twice? Do you know what that instruction does?

Comment: The first `mov $0, %eax` is there because _"printf uses a variable number of arguments and %rax specifies how many SSE registers are used for the arguments "_. The second one is there because presumably this function is supposed to return 0. If you didn't zero out `eax` again you'd be returning what `printf` returned, i.e. the number of characters written by `printf`.

Comment: @Michael oh thx man, where i can read about it, and can give more information

Comment: You can google e.g. _"x86_64 calling convention"_ and _"x86_64 vararg eax"_.

Comment: This looks like unoptimized machine code.  If the compiler is not allowed to optimize the code, random pointless instructions may appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sub $0x10,%rsp` allocates space on the stack, it's the same as doing `pushq 0` twice except that the value in the allocated stack space will not necessarily be zero, but this is ok since the `mov` instructions used later replace the garbage with real data.

As Michael rightly stated the `mov $0x0,%eax` is because `printf` (as well as any other varargs function) takes the number of arguments in `rax`.